# How to call PHP SOAP Web services in android PhoneGap

Tags: php, android, cordova, nusoap

I create SOAP services on PHP and call from Android PhoneGap. I don't know where to start from...can any one say regarding this...

can anyone refer me any sample tutorial or an example to do so.. thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried AJAX?

Comment: No, I don't have any idea about programming with phonegap. Can you give me some example ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23577298/6124074) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Take a look of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example

Comment: Which technology is better than the others JavaScript,Ajax, JQuery ?

Comment: Javascript is the language, AJAX is a set of techniques used to make asynchronous requests and JQuery is a Javascript Framework

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery ,you can use this JQuery Plugin to make the request

https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap

you can base on this tutorial as well,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12816/JavaScript-SOAP-Client

Or you can base on answers of this question.